# HTTP POST request works on emulator, but doesn't on real device

Tags: java, android, http-post

I built a simple app which gets data from a remote database using HTTP POST requests. I decided to change its layout, but now the requests I realize doesn't work on a real device.

I simply change the layout and copied the same classes on this new project. I can't understand what's wrong. When I use the app it stops on the splash screen activity and waits there. I looked into the code and I noticed that I stops when are performed the POST requests.
When I execute the project on the emulater, it works perfectly.

This is my class:

```
public class MyHttpPostRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

private String link;
private String querySql;

public MyHttpPostRequest(String remoteLink, String richiestaSql) {
    this.link = remoteLink;
    this.querySql = richiestaSql;
}

@Override
protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {

    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(this.link);

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("query", this.querySql));

    StringBuffer stringBuffer = null;

    String[] token = new String[600];

    try {
        UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
        request.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse response= httpClient.execute(request);

        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String LineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        int i=0;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(line + LineSeparator); 
            token[i] = line + LineSeparator;
            i++;
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch(Exception e){

    }

    return token;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}

public void eseguiRichiesta(){
    this.execute(this.link, this.querySql);
}

public void setValues(String remoteLink, String richiestaSql){
    this.link = remoteLink;
    this.querySql = richiestaSql;
}   

public void setLink(String link){
    this.link = link;
}

public void setRequest(String requestSQL){
    this.querySql = requestSQL;
}
}
```

Comment: Are you really using a splashscreen on an Android app?

Comment: Yes, I use it because on the backdround I check the database's congruence... So I don't want the app to be just a white screen.
When I say splashscreen I mean that the whole screen is covered from an image with a progress bar on it...

Comment: Why not using a progress indicator? http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/

Comment: I'll consider your suggestion in future, but now my priority is the HTTP POST request problem. Thank you for you suggestion...

Comment: post your stack trace if your app crashes crash details are logged in logcat.

Comment: It's all ok, the app just stops on the request so I simply see the splashscreen and the progress bar... It does't crash, it simply doesn't go on.

Comment: at wich line does the code stop? Is the token null or empty? In your postExecute, you have no code, what should happen?

Comment: postExecute is never used. When I execute this class I call "eseguiRichiesta()" and then I use the "get()" method so I wait until the request is finished. I've put some "Log" in the code and it seems that the "doInBackground" portion is never processed.